# INVALID_ARGUMENT when sending V3 reCAPTCHA token for assessment

Tags: ios, swift, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

We are getting an error when sending reCAPTCHA tokens for assessment.

The token is produced on the client using the **RecaptchaEnterprise.xcframework** and should be sent from our backend to Google.

This is the code that instantiate the client:

```
    private func activateReCAPTCHA() {
    _Concurrency.Task {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let (recaptchaClient, error) = await Recaptcha.getClient(Resources.recaptchaKey)
            if let error {
                print("RecaptchaClient creation error: \(String(describing: error.errorMessage)).")
                error.reportToExternalServices()
            } else if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                appDelegate.recaptchaClient = recaptchaClient
                print("RecaptchaClient created.")
            } else {
                print("RecaptchaClient creation error: AppDelegate not available.")
            }
            sleep(0)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that requests and receives the token:

```
extension RecaptchaClient {
    static var client: RecaptchaClient? {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.recaptchaClient
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

private func fetchReCAPTCHAToken() {
    guard let recaptchaClient = RecaptchaClient.client else {
        print("fetchReCAPTCHAToken: RecaptchaClient not found")
        return
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        Task {
            let (token, error) = await recaptchaClient.execute(RecaptchaAction(action: .login))
            if let token = token {
                print("fetchReCAPTCHAToken: \(token.recaptchaToken)")
            } else {
                print("fetchReCAPTCHAToken: \(String(describing: error?.errorMessage))")
            }
            sleep(0)
        }
    }
}
```

So far everything is good.
To simulate the backend, I created a cURL script that sends the following json, with the generated token pasted from the xCode console:

```
  {
      "event": {
          "token": "...",
          "siteKey": "...",
          "expectedAction": "login"
      }
  }
```

The method is POST and the URL is of the following structure:

https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../assessments?key=...

The response:

```
{

  "error": {
      "code": 400,

      "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",

      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

We did the same with Postman and had the same result.
What might be the reason for that?

---- Update ----

We were finally able to get a valid response by doing the following:

1. Log into the Google Cloud console
2. From the CLI, run a cURL to the following address:
   "https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../assessments?access_token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

When compared to the previous attempts, the only difference is that the CLI script uses an OAUTH2 access_token= instead of a key=.
So we conclude that the problem is probably in the key= argument. The value we are using for the key= argument is the **secret key** that has the following description: **Use this secret key for communication between your site and reCAPTCHA**. The question is still open for anyone who has a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check your `siteKey` argument. Note this should be your reCAPTCHA Enterprise [site key](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key), not a GCP [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). Nor is it your "private" key if you migrated from reCAPTCHA v2 or v3 to reCAPTCHA Enterprise.

Note that the `?key=` query param in the request is the [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) though if this was not correct it would manifest as an auth error, not an invalid argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it seems that this value is correct. See the --Update-- section

Comment: @ArikSegal The `key=` is not for your secret key, it is for your API key. The secret key is if you have a reCAPTCHA v2 integration, then you pass it to the legacy `siteverify` API `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your_secret&response=response_string&remoteip=user_ip_address`